# Sql get specific Column from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
id | tempname | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6
-----------------------------------------------------------
1  |    1     |   on |  off |  off  |  on  |  off |    off
-----------------------------------------------------------
2  |     2    |  off |   off|  on   | off  |  off |   on
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

> I want get data from above table whose value is on and i dont want another column i want only those column who has value on

Result:
This is my table

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
id | tempname | col1 | col3 | col4 | col6
-----------------------------------------------------------
1  |    1     |   on |  off |  on  | off
-----------------------------------------------------------
2  |     2    |  off | on  |  off  | on
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

i dont want any extra columns
and i wanted to do using select * query.
I dont want to specify columns name in select query

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: mysql. Thankx gurv

Comment: I'd suggest you redesign your table.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to look at each column in turn (using information_schema columns) and check to see if any rows have the 'on' value, then keep track of those and then create a custom sql statement from the columns that you found that do have at least one row with that on value.

This code below works for sql server, you will need to adjust it for use with mySql.

You could then create a stored procedure from this and then just execute that

NB. The code may be slow for very large tables, even though the part that checks to see if there are any "ons" for each column only check for the first occurrence found (using TOP 1)

```
DECLARE @sqlCountOn NVARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @colName nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @countOn int
DECLARE @colsToInclude NVARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @columnWildcard NVARCHAR(50)

-- define the columns you always want in the query results
SET @colsToInclude = 'id,tempname'
set @tableName='test'
set @columnWildcard = 'col%'

-- get a list of columns to check for on/off using a wildcard on the name
DECLARE columnCursor cursor for SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
               WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName and COLUMN_NAME like @columnWildcard order by ordinal_position
OPEN columnCursor   

FETCH NEXT FROM columnCursor INTO @colName
--loop through all the columns that we want to look for on/off
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   

       --build a query to count if we have *any* 'on's we have for this column
       SET @sqlCountOn = 'select @retValOut= COUNT(*) from (select top 1 ' + @colName + ' from ' + @tableName + ' where ' + @colName + '=''on'')'
       SET @ParmDefinition = N'@retvalOUT int OUTPUT';

       EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCountOn, @ParmDefinition, @retvalOUT=@countOn OUTPUT;
       --check the count and if it's greater than 0 we want to include it, so add the column name to the output column list
       if @countOn >0 set @colsToInclude=@colsToInclude + ',' + @colName 

       FETCH NEXT FROM columnCursor INTO @colName   
END

CLOSE columnCursor   
DEALLOCATE columnCursor

--now create the query that will output just the columns we want from the table
set @query='select ' + @colsToInclude + ' from [' + @tableName + '] '

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```